# Is there a way to use a VB Dll in c++ (preferably cross-plattform)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to interact with a piece of hardware using my own code. The vendor offers a dll on his website with some sample code in C#, the DLL seems to be compiled from Visual Basic.
I'm wondering how to use this DLL in C++. Is C++/CLI the only way to do this? Or is there some other way that allows me to keep my code Cross-Platform compatible?

Comment: COM is one way - is it a .net dll or a vb classic dll?

Comment: Please expand on cross-platform. The vast majority of platforms cannot run a VB DLL, so it would be good to know what platforms you are targeting so we can weed out the low-hanging fruit by eliminating the impossible.

Comment: DLLs are Windows-only and almost the same is the case for C# / CLI. Linux uses .so files for shared libraries.

Comment: As a rule of thumb the _Visual_ in VB and whatnot means MS/Win only.

Answer (score 0):

simple example: suppose we have a managed class Hello in a .NET assembly (hello.dll).

```
    //This is c# but it could be also vb. Compilator of c# and VB.net  translate it to same thing .Net assembly dll. Which is internaly exactly the same  as c# dll.
    class Hello
    {
        public void HelloWorld()
        {
            Console.Writeline("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Now we need to define a native proxy class for Hello:

```
class Hello
{
public:
    Hello() : wrapper_("hello.dll", "namespace name") {}
    void HelloWorld()
    {
        wrapper_("Hello");
    }
private:
    nativeAdapter::NativeProxy wrapper_;
};
}
```

In our main function, we can use the proxy as if it were the managed class:

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    Namespace::Hello hello;
    hello.Hello();
    return 0;
}
```